# Deeplearning4j: How would I prepare this data for a RNN that uses LSTM?

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

In my code, I download data from a source to a CSV file, then I apply a transformation process to it, after which it is written to a final CSV file. At this point in time, one row of my data looks like this:

> 45.414001,10358500,45.698002,44.728001,0.0

The first column is the data I want to predict, and the final column(the one with the 0s) is just a place holder for now, it will be a double number. Using deeplearning4j, I then load this data from the CSV file into a recordreader. Here is what that looks like:

```
RecordReader recordReader = new CSVRecordReader(numSkipLines);



recordReader.initialize(new FileSplit(inputPath));
```

So my question is, what should I do next? I want to use this data with a RNN LSTM model, which will predict the first column, one step into the future. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, depending on how much data/rows you have, you separate between training and testing data. Testing data can usually be a bit smaller than your training data as the testing is just to see if your model predicts effectively.

The training data should be split between a smaller training and a validation set. You should be able to use the validation set to see after how many epochs/rounds of training do you being to overfit/underfit. You want to train to when the model just begins to overfit.